User not logging out after deleting cookie
I'm hosting a project on render and something with the logout is not working. It redirects to the login page and deletes the cookie, which I'm able to confirm in the console and headers. However, when I click the back button or re-launch the app, which navigates to the home page by default, It shows the user that is suppose to be logged out, still logged in, and the cookie is still there.
I first thought it could be some sort of re-rendering issue so I got rid of the dependencies in the useEffect, but the issue is still there.
I've also suspected it could be a cache problem so I set the profile response header to no-cache, but this didn't work either.
I tried putting the logout functionality in it's own component and importing it to the header component in case the two being in the same component was a problem, but this didn't work.
I wrapped the useEffect logic in an if statement that checks if the user is logged in before fetching the profile, and still nothing.
Here's the frontend:
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";
import axios from "axios";

function Header() {
  const { setUserInfo, userInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
  // const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserData() {
      try {
        // if (isLoggedIn) {
          const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/profile`, {
            withCredentials: true,
          });
  
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setUserInfo(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            // setIsLoggedIn(true);
          }
        // }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (err.response.status === 401 && Object.keys(userInfo).length === 0) {
          navigate("/login");
        }
        if (err.response.status === 401 && Object.keys(userInfo).length > 0) {
          alert("Session has expired");
          navigate("/login");
        }
      }
    }

    if (Object.keys(userInfo).length === 0) {
      fetchUserData();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userInfo);
  }, [userInfo]);

  async function logoutHandler() {
    try{
const response = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/logout`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // setIsLoggedIn(false);
          setUserInfo({});
          navigate("/login");
        }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  async function deleteAcctHandler() {
    try {
      const shouldDelete = window.confirm(
        "Are you sure you want to delete your account?"
      );
      if (shouldDelete) {
        const response = await axios.delete(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/profile/${userInfo.id}`,
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setUserInfo({})
          // setIsLoggedIn(false);
          navigate("/login");
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <Link to="/" className="logo">
        CRUD's Book Store
      </Link>
      <nav>
        {Object.keys(userInfo).length > 0 && (
          <>
            <span className="username">Logged in as {userInfo.username}</span>
            <div>
              <Link className="new-book-link" to={"/create"}>
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  strokeWidth={1.5}
                  stroke="currentColor"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    d="M12 4.5v15m7.5-7.5h-15"
                  />
                </svg>
                Add new book
              </Link>
              <a className="logout" href="#" onClick={logoutHandler}>
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  strokeWidth={1.5}
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  className="w-6 h-6"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15M12 9l-3 3m0 0l3 3m-3-3h12.75"
                  />
                </svg>
                Logout
              </a>
              <a className="delete" href="#" onClick={deleteAcctHandler}>
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  strokeWidth={1.5}
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  className="w-6 h-6"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0"
                  />
                </svg>
                Delete account
              </a>
            </div>
          </>
        )}

        {Object.keys(userInfo).length === 0 && (
          <>
            <Link to={"/login"}>Login</Link>
            <Link to={"/register"}>Register</Link>
          </>
        )}
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;


Here's the backend for the profile:
app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { token } = req.cookies;
    
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        if (err.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
          res.status(401).json({ message: "Token has expired" });
        } else if (err.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
          res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
        } else {
          res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
        }
      } else {
       // res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store');
        res.json(info);
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});


For the logout:
app.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("token",{ path: '/' }).json("cookie deleted");
});

Incase it helps, how the cookie is set:
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(username, password);

    if (!username || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username and password are required" });
    }

    const q = "SELECT * FROM bv9bjjshw2vksyyiknwr.users WHERE username = ?";

    db.query(q, [username], (err, data) => {
      console.log("Query Error:", err);
      console.log("Query Result:", data);
      if (err) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      if (data.length === 1) {
        const { id, username, password: storedPass } = data[0];
        console.log("Entered password:", password);
        console.log("Stored hashed password:", storedPass);
        const passMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, storedPass);
        if (passMatch) {
          jwt.sign(
            {
              id,
              username,
            },
            secret,
            {
              expiresIn: "1h",
            },
            (err, token) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                res.cookie("token", token, { 
                  secure: true, 
                  sameSite: 'none' 
                }).json({ id, username });
              }
            }
          );
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid username or password" });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});


